# Why bloc's variable doesn't update after adding event to update it

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Part of my router.dart:

```
routes: <RouteBase>[
        GoRoute(
          name: RouteConstants.progressListingScreen,
          path: 'progress-listing',
          builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
            final album = state.extra! as AlbumEntity;
            context.read<ProgressBloc>().add(ProgressesLoadEvent(album));
            return const ProgressListingPage();
          },
          routes: <RouteBase>[
            GoRoute(
              name: RouteConstants.progressAddingScreen,
              path: 'add',
              builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
                return const AddProgrssPage();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

I have update the bloc's `album` variable with `context.read<ProgressBloc>().add(ProgressesLoadEvent(album));` before routes to ProgressListingPage. But in ProgressListingPage, I try to access the album with `context.read<ProgressBloc>().album`, it said the album is `null`. If I use, `context.watch<ProgressBloc>().album`, it will be null at first, then not null anymore. Why is it so? And how to fix it.

Your help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can you include full sample widget and share a gist